# email alerts in pipeline with condition using datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make the sending of emails depend on the execution environment so that other  business users don’t get flooded with mails coming from a lower environment i.e test or dev

The email should be only send to the business from the production.

I am using the following code as dynamic content for the if condition however this is very specific to only one environment:

```
@equals(pipeline().DataFactory,'AdPrd117')
```

[image: 1]

However, if I can make the above dynamic content more robust for all the 3 environments then is there a way: where I can use the if condition as below :
if data factory name.

Is there a possibility that we can make the email alerts getting generated(alerts which is with the help of a notebook) for each environment(dev, test, prod) and for a specific email id that can be added to the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

We set up our DataFactory with a suffix that indicates the environment (`Dev`, `Tst`, `Prod`).

I have the following expression that checks which environment a pipeline is running in to figure out which directory of an SFTP Server to use (Development, Test, or Production):

```
@if(
    startswith(
        pipeline().DataFactory
        , 'dev'
    )
    , 'Development'
    , if(
        startswith(
            pipeline().DataFactory
            , 'tst'
        )
        , 'Test'
    , 'Production'
    )
)
```

Likewise, we use similar code to process our cubes, and to figure out which LogicApp to use to send messages (we have 1 logic app per environment).

Edit:

Based on the comments, maybe this would help you. This assumes your environments have a consistent naming convention, and your dev/test ones do not contain `prd`.

Create a variable called Recipient of type string in your pipeline. Then add a Set Variable component to your pipeline. Give it the name  "Set recipient" on the General tab, and then on the Variables Tab, set the name to the "Recipient" variable you just created.

In the Value field, use the following:

```
@if(
    equals(
        substring(pipeline().DataFactory, 2, 3)
        , 'Prd'
    )
    , 'MyBusinessUsers@contoso.com'
    , 'MyDevelopers@contoso.com'
)
```

[image: Example]

This means you now have a variable which will contain the group you want to send mails to, depending on the name of the ADF name.

Comment: The alerts are being sent in every environment however the requirement is to make it specific for prod and dev ,test alerts can be sent to another concerned person

Comment: @hari_agg - We have that working too., Our Logic App takes a receiver parameter. The Logic App is called from a specific pipeline that can set the recipient. We use the same trick as above to figure out which environment and then pick the recipient. An alternative could be to store such things in a KeyVault, and simply change the values of the secret there to use the specific mail account/group.

Comment: I tried with the help of Key vault however the suggestion came in to use the environment variables so how is that according to the requirement

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are struggling with, to be honest. If you use the function syntax I supplied in my answer, you can use that to set a variable. You can use it to set 1 variable containing the specific alert that indicates which environment, and a second variable that contains the recipient(s). That way your code would work for all environments. The disadvantage is that if the list of recipients or the alert changes, you would have to update and republish the ADF pipelines. Using a keyvault would avoid having to do that.

Comment: In the OP, you state you want to replace the hardcoded `AdPrd117` value with something dynamic for all three environments. Then you later on state in your comment you have it working in all 3 environments. If that is the case, then please update the OP, and clarify what the issue is. Our answers are based on the information you provide, so if the question differs from what actually is true, we cannot know that.

Comment: the hardcoding is fine just the only this is that the emails to be sent to respective groups based on the environment for example dev,test alerts to group A and prod alerts to group B

Comment: @hari_agg - I added an edit with an updated example.

Comment: i am using a config file and passing all the email id respectively. Reading the file using the lookup and in the set I am using the dynamic content as @activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Dv1178. So is there a way where I can make it dynamic and make it pipeline specific example 
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Dv1178 
or @activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Tst1179 as when the pipeline is executed it uses the pipeline name specific to the environment

Comment: I think you should create a new question. List *all* your requirements and whatever you have done so far and why your current implementation isn't working. Hiding details in comments is a waste of everybody's time.